# np.genfromtxt value error on python (with csv. file)

Tags: python, numpy, csv, genfromtxt

```
current_account = np.genfromtxt(fname = "q3_1_current_account.csv",delimiter = ",")
current_account
```

I want to upload a csv file to my python, but it makes an error.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[10], line 3
      1 # your code here
      2 # q3_1
----> 3 current_account = np.genfromtxt(fname = "q3_1_current_account.csv",delimiter = ",")
      4 current_account

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py:2145, in genfromtxt(fname, dtype, comments, delimiter, skip_header, skip_footer, converters, missing_values, filling_values, usecols, names, excludelist, deletechars, replace_space, autostrip, case_sensitive, defaultfmt, unpack, usemask, loose, invalid_raise, max_rows, encoding, like)
   2143 # Raise an exception ?
   2144 if invalid_raise:
-> 2145     raise ValueError(errmsg)
   2146 # Issue a warning ?
   2147 else:
   2148     warnings.warn(errmsg, ConversionWarning, stacklevel=2)

ValueError: Some errors were detected !
    Line #2 (got 501 columns instead of 280)
    Line #3 (got 507 columns instead of 280)
    Line #4 (got 388 columns instead of 280)
    Line #5 (got 375 columns instead of 280)
    Line #6 (got 282 columns instead of 280)
```

I have to use np.genfromtxt to do my task. Can you help me what is wrong with my code?

(The picture below is the part of csv file. And there are no any blank values.)
[image]

Comment: do you have the right delimiter?  All rows should have the same number of columns.  Your's does not.

Comment: Do any of the column numbers look right?  What's that picture?  excel?  doesn't look like raw text.  Even if the columns are consistent, the first row  looks like a text header, and the first columns are also text.  `genfrontext` does not automatically handle those.

Comment: Your screenshot is unclear, but do you have commas in some of those values?  If the columns are determined by commas, then the values cannot have commas since those will be split used to create columns.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at screenshot you provided I smell that `np.genfromtxt()` chokes on some data from your header row (like these in very first columns), so I'd skip that row with use of `skip_headers`:

```
current_account = np.genfromtxt(fname="q3_1_current_account.csv", delimiter=",", skip_header=1)
```

Comment: might also need to use `usecols` to skip the text columns.